# $K|\mathbb{Q}_p$ un-ramified if and only if $(d_K)=(1)$: help with a passage

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I need some help in th last passage of this proof:

> Suppose $K|\mathbb{Q}_p$ is un-ramified and of degree $n$. then $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ can be taken to be an integral unit in $\mathcal{O}_K$. It's enough to show that the discriminant of $K|\mathbb{Q}_p$, denoted with $d_K$, is the trivial ideal $(1)$. We can use the integral basis $\{\alpha^i\}_1^n$ to compute it, and the fact that the extensions is separable. So $$(d_k)=(\det (\sigma_j\alpha^i))^2$$ where $\sigma_j$ are the $n$ embeddings of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ in the algebraic closure of $K$. It's easy to see that such determinant is a Vandermonde determinant and it's equal to $$ \prod_{j<k}(\sigma_j\alpha - \sigma_k \alpha)^2$$

**Then according to my lecturer**, such determinant is clearly an integral unit, ending the proof. I really don't see why this is true: I tried to prove that each single element in the product is invertible (in the integral ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$) but the presence of the minus sign ruins this approach. I fear there is some kind of trick in this case, but I can't see it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it seems that you are trying to prove the implication "$K/\mathbb Q_p$ unramified $\Rightarrow$ $\mathfrak d_{K/\mathbb Q_p} = \mathcal O_K$". Also, you didn't tell us what definition of unramified you are using (this might be relevant when you try to prove that two definitions are equivalent...). I will use:

**Lemma.** Let $K/\mathbb Q_p$ be a finite extension. Then $K$ is unramified if and only if the reduction map
\begin{align*}
f \colon \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p) &\to \operatorname{Gal}(k/\mathbb F_p)\\
\sigma &\mapsto \bar \sigma
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

**Answer to your question.** If $K/\mathbb Q_p$ is unramified, then $f$ is an isomorphism. In particular, if $\sigma_i \neq \sigma_j$, then $\bar \sigma_i \neq \bar \sigma_j$. This shows that $\sigma_i(\alpha) - \sigma_j(\alpha)$ has to be a unit: if not, then $\bar \sigma_i(\bar \alpha) = \bar \sigma_j(\bar \alpha)$ (since $\mathbb Z_p$ is a local ring), which forces $\bar \sigma_i = \bar \sigma_j$ (since $\bar \alpha$ generates $k$ over $\mathbb F_p$), contradiction. $\square$

Comment: I don't see why $\sigma_i(\alpha)-\sigma_j(\alpha)$ has to be an integer unit if non zero. I need to show that it is an integer unit (i.e. the inverse is an integer as well) and not only invertible (which is trivial). Am I missing something?

Comment: I use that $\sigma_i(\alpha) - \sigma_j(\alpha)$ is either a unit, or divisible by $p$. This is because $\mathbb Z_p$ is a local ring.

Comment: I overlooked this fact, that might be the missing step. I'll think over it for a while! :)

Comment: ok I think I got your argument, just to be on the safe side, I'll write a little commentary on your proof, could you please check it and tell me if I understood every passage? 
first of all, unramified ext, is a Galois ext, hence we can work with the galois group. Then we know that $\prod \sigma_j(\alpha)-\sigma_j(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Being local, it's enough to show that it doesn't lie in $(p)$. Assume it, and quotient out the maximal idea of $K$, call it $(\pi)$. So we have $\prod \bar{\sigma_i}(\bar{\alpha})-\bar{\sigma_j}(\bar{\alpha})=0$. since now we are working in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: it must be that for some $j$ and $i$, $\bar{\sigma_i}(\bar{\alpha})=\bar{\sigma_i}(\bar{\alpha})$, hence equality of the two automorphisms and hence contradiction as you wrote

Comment: Right. Or to be slightly more precise, we're working in what I've been calling $k$: the finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$ that is the residue field of $K$.